# Host files on cloud from an app

Tags: java, android, file, upload, cloud

I'm doing an app similar to Instagram. I want to save the files that the users upload to the app to a central server. I have tried different solutions but none has worked. My idea is use Box, Google Drive, Mega or similar to host these files. I had implemented some of these but always they ask for the credentials to the users and if the user has an account, the file finally is hosted in his cloud. ¿Is it possible does a central file server from the app without asking for the credentials with these services or know you some service that fulfills my objective? I'm searching for a service that offers a free space with an expandable space paying a fee. (Like Box, Drive...)

Thank you and sorry for my English.

Comment: No.  Think about it- unless you want a document to be public to the world, there needs to be some way of proving who you are so you can access it.  That means authentication.  Which means you need their authentication info.  Now instead of authenticating the user, you could authenticate your app and use an account made by your app-  but then you need to securely store authentication data, and if its a common account then you need to be able to tell which documents belong to whom (meaning they need to log in with your service and you provide file lists via api).

Comment: Yes, the idea is authenticate the app, but is possible to do with Drive, Box...? Any clue to how to do it? I need ideas and I think that I will can do... Thanks for your answer

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/  Other services are available. It is up to you to investigate and decide based on the needs of your app.

Comment: I'm comming from web enviroment with PHP and in the web I have idea of how upload files to the hosting but from android I don't know if it's the same system or I need other "host" to save the files. I have exploring other alternatives and I found Back4App, but I don't find how upload files from and android app... Someone can explain me how work the hostings from android? I see that is not the same than from a website. I'm very lost :(

Answer (score 0):

After investigate a lot, and with the help of your answers I had found the way to store files on a central server from Android.

I want to highlight two ways:

- Using a Parse Server
- Using Google Firebase

The two options are very well documented and you can try they for free.

I have tried back4app.com and buddy.com for Parse server and the free tier of Google Firebase and I have decided to use any Parse server instead of Firebase for the independece that this platform offers.